# async/await problems getting system to wait for response

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

I have an email that uses web requests to get the different parts(text, html and subject).  I want the program to get them at the same time to reduce time.  I have written a simplified version below of what I am trying to achieve.

```
public static async Task<MailMessage> GetEmailMessage(string subjectUrl, string bodyUrl)
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage();

    var subjectTask = new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(subjectUrl);
    var bodyTask = new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(bodyUrl);

    mailMessage.Subject = await subjectTask;
    mailMessage.Body = await bodyTask;

    return mailMessage;
}
```

I would like the program to for the subject and the body and once it has both, return the MailMessage.

I am new to this async, any help would be appreciated.

**========= SOLUTION =========**

So thanks to @SLaks for making me realise the problem wasn't in my function.  It was in the way I was calling it.  Turns out, in my case (I think cause I am returning a reference type not a value type), I had to call the Task<>.Result before it would actually do the waiting.

ie: This will **NOT** wait for completion:

```
var mailMessage = GetEmailMessage("urlhere", "http://www.google.com");
```

But this will (Notice the "Result" being called for:

```
var mailMessage = GetEmailMessage("urlhere", "http://www.google.com").Result;
```

I hope this post helps someone else with the same problem.
Happy coding!

Comment: You are synchronously waiting for the result of an async operation.  This is rarely a good idea.  You should make the calling method `async` and `await` your asynchronous operation instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what your code does.

Calling `GetStringAsync()` will kick off an asynchronous request.

When you `await` the first one, your method will stop executing until that one finishes; the other request will still be executing during that time.

Had you `await`ed the first task before kicking off the second task, it would not have done what you want.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I step through the code it gets to the await statements and immediately exists the function and carries on with my program.  I want it to stop at the "await subjectTask" until it has finished and then stop at the "await bodyTask" until it has finished, then once both are finished, I want it to return to my program.

Comment: Ahhhh, found my mistake, solution added to question.  Thanks for the help!